# Why can't I run my getline code without the stringstream? How do i use stringstream to make this code work?

Tags: c++, getline, stringstream

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main() {   
    string randomwords,temp;
    getline(cin,randomwords);
    while(getline(randomwords,temp,' ')) {  
        cout<<temp<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::getline`'s first parameter is a `std::basic_istream`. There is no conversion between a `std::basic_string` and a `std::basic_istream`, so you cannot pass a `std::string` (a specialization of `std::basic_string`) as a first parameter to `std::getline`. This is a fundamental rule of C++, parameters to functions must have matching types or have one of several conversions that can be used to convert an object of one type to the other one. There are none here, so that's why it won't work.

However, `std::basic_istringstream` has an overloaded constructor that takes a `std::basic_string` as a parameter. Normally that can be used as an implicit conversion, but this particular constructor is an `explicit` constructor which prohibits it from being used in implicit type conversions. Therefore you'll just do the job yourself: construct an input stream from a string explicitly, and `std::getline` will happily use it. Mission accomplished.